# How to do a "simple" find and replace in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I am new to jquery, and I'm having trouble doing what I thought should be a very simple find and replace operation.

I want to change the text inside the the "<p>" tags. So for instance I might want to replace "*your title*" with "*a title*".

```
  <div id="ValidationSummary">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>
                Please specify your title</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>
                Please enter your first name</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>
                Please enter your surname</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

and here is the jQuery which isn't doing anything:

```
$(function() {
    $('#ValidationSummary').text().replace("your title", "a title");
    $('#ValidationSummary').text().replace("first name", "christian name");
    $('#ValidationSummary').text().replace("your surname", "your last name");
};
```

I really cannot see what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Please help, thanks

Comment: .text() isn't suppose to be used like that, it should be:
$('#ValidationSummary').text($(this).text().replace("your title", "a title"));

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any changes to strings in JS always produces a **new string**, rather than modifying what was there. Fortunately jQuery makes it easy to both retrieve and modify text at the same time:

```
$('#ValidationSummary p').text(function (i, old) {
     return old
         .replace('your title', 'a title')
         .replace('first name', 'christian name')
         .replace('your surname', 'your last name');
});
```

---

Explanation:

- `return`ing a string from `.text()` tells jQuery to replace what was there (passed in as `old`) with this new string.
- Since `replace()` returns a new string each time, we can chain multiple calls together, so that we only need one `.text()` call and `return` statement.
- I used the selector `'#ValidationSummary p'` since using `.text()` or `.html()` **will replace the entire contents** of the element it is operating on.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function() {
    var text = $('#ValidationSummary').text().replace("title", "your title"); // this will give the text after replacement, but it will not set the text to ValidationSummary
    $('#ValidationSummary').text(text);

    text = $('#ValidationSummary').text().replace("first name", "christian name");
    $('#ValidationSummary').text(text);

    text = $('#ValidationSummary').text().replace("your postcode", "your zipcode");
    $('#ValidationSummary').text(text);
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this was almost perfect, but accepted answer was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

On [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EnDnX/8/).

```
$(function() {
    $('#ValidationSummary').html($('#ValidationSummary').html().replace("title", "Mister"));
    $('#ValidationSummary').html($('#ValidationSummary').html().replace("first name", "ABC"));
    $('#ValidationSummary').html($('#ValidationSummary').html().replace("surname", "XYZ"));       
});
```

Works but don't think it's reliable.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS...

```
 $('#ValidationSummary').text($('#ValidationSummary').find('P').text().replace("title", "your title"));
 $('#ValidationSummary').text($('#ValidationSummary').find('P').text().replace("first name", "christian name"));
 $('#ValidationSummary').text($('#ValidationSummary').find('P').text().replace("your postcode", "your zipcode"));
```